# Connecting firebase to Angular JS - possible json issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The question is how to format firebase to work with angular. I have a view that works with ng as a static view. In the $scope it is defined like this

```
$scope.standardItems = [{
    name: "The Name",
    sizeX: 2,
    sizeY: 1,
    row: 0,
    col: 0
}, {......etc
```

But if I try and supply data from firebase it does not work probably because the output is not formatted correctly. The connection seems fine and I can add data but firebase adds it own id. This is the how the data looks exported from the firebase console

```
{
    "-KdJVcYUXMfeym3jPy04" : {
    "att" : "grid",
    "col" : 0,
    "id" : 1487476528646,
    "name" : "This is a test grid",
    "row" : 0,
    "sizeX" : 2,
    "sizeY" : 1
},
```

The extra parameters are not important but the nesting probably is. I have logged the out put of the firebase array using this

```
var todosRef = new Firebase('https://xxxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/');
$scope.todos = $firebaseArray(todosRef);
console.log($scope.todos);
```

And I get this in the chrome debug console

```
Array[0]
    0:Object
        $id: "-KjhbuvgtVvFUnbfbmj04"
        $priority:null
        att:"grid"
        col:0
        id:1487476528646
        name:"This is a test grid"
        row:0
        sizeX:2
        sizeY:1
    __proto__
```

Here is the important line from the view using angular ng-repeat

```
<li gridster-item row="item.position[0]" col="item.position[1]" size-x="item.size.x" size-y="item.size.y" ng-repeat="item in todos">
    //..
</li>
```

My question is how do I pass to angular (the view) exactly what is being passed in the static example above from the controller? How can I "print" exactly what is being passed to angular from the array - the export from firebase console and chrome log console are not totally the same. It does not help that all the parent nodes are unique non sequential IDs such as -KdJVcYUXMfeym3jPy04 as it is  not  obvious how to strip them off again - or how to use a word such as "grid". Do I need a wildcard in the path  and if so what is it? The code works using a static local array so it is all about reading json from firebase.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I hope this answer is helpful. There is nothing wrong with the code posted here! Angular js will read firebase without any changes and the outputs from the chrome console and the firebase console should look like they are here even with the "-adgadhfe445ggh45" added id index. In my case I made a syntax error that excluded the ng-repeat from the the controller because it fell outside and its closing div

But at least we now know that we do not need any code to reformat the firebase.